Embed font-files .ttf into an already existing Pdf in Java
I need to embed a .ttf-File into an existing Pdf in Java. Now I would prefer both Pdfbox and openpdf, but I am open to any suggestion.
The Java-webservice is to

open the Pdf,

then insert the .ttf

and then close the pdf without saving the pdf to harddisk (the pdf will be later transformed into bytearray and send out).


I do not even know where to start.
I was expecting the file and the fonts to be shown in the list of fonts of the pdf.

What does 'not closing' the pdf mean? Surely it can only mean holding the whole transformed thing in memory? If so, is that really your plan?

You can save to a ByteArrayOutputStream. However "insert the ttf" isn't as easy as you think. I've done it in the past but only for simple fonts (type 1 and truetype, not type 0)

The problem is not saving the pdf to a bytestream, I am doing that one already. I am talking only about imprinting the .ttf into the pdf, noting else. Why is that not possible? I used to do that via ghostscript, why is taht not possible via java or itext?

The saving was one of your questions. You need to have some minimum experience how the PDF structure is (open one of them with PDFDebugger). The fonts are in the page resources, however resources can have "Forms XObjects" which can have resources as well, thus fonts. The trick is to replace these fonts with new font objects that embed the font (and also to find the correct font). This is like 5 different SO questions in one.

I am sorry, saving the pdf was not intended to be part of the question. Do You have an example code?

No, I wrote such code last year for work but don't have access to that code anymore; a user also wrote such code but that is that users code, so I would have to recreate it from memory and it takes some time, and I think you should also do a minimum of work.
